# How to read PLC tag to CIMPLICITY screen

Tags: scada

Hi Somehow got GE Cimplicity 8.2 demo version.
Now I started learning it....

How to read a Omron PLC tag to Cimplicity. I have Omron PLC & HMI experience, where PLC register address i will assign on the HMI bargraph object suppose. so based on PLC register's value bargraph will show the display.

How to achieve the same in Cimplicity screen and run to see the display of bargraph

Also any material/sample code helpful for learning basics highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need Industrial Geteway OPC server to read the tag before add new port & device on cimplicity project.